# How can I have a variable accessible in whole solution C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

**How can I have a variable accessible in whole solution C# asp.net**

-- I have tried Application Variables that are accessible within the project but **I need to store a dataTable that should be accessible in whole solution**

Comment: If your entire application needs access to this data table, then your application is broken. You'd be better off fixing it, so that only a data access layer have access to the table, rather than bodging it by making a globally accessible static.

Answer (score 2):

You can create constants in a shared assembly.

Ex:

```
public static class MyConstants
{
  public static string MyFirstConstant{get{return "shared value";}}
}
```

All projects that share the assembly where this class is defined can use this constant.
You can expose a DataTable the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Create a public static class which contains the variable.

```
public static class Container
{
    public static int GlobalInt;
}
```

Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information on static classes.

Put this class into an assembly which can be accessed by every other project.